# Laravel AppServiceProvider Auth::guard('admin')->check() not working

Tags: laravel

I'd like to share data with all views via the AppServiceProvider. Moreover, I'd like to check the guard type first to give some specific output for each user type.

I tried to check the guard in AppServiceProvider via `Auth::guard('admin')->check()` but it returns false. However, the same if statement works perfectly in my Controllers.
I've also included `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` and `Illuminate\Support\Facades\View`.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {

            // Share data with views

        }
    }
}
```

The if statement returns false, although I'm logged in as admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need view composer for this.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Auth;
use DB;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
        {
            if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {

            }   
        });  
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

If you want to pass data in views.

```php
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
        {
            if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
                 $admin = DB::table('admins')->first();  // for example
                 $view->with(compact('admin'));
            }   
        });
```